# Showing that $(S,d)$ is a metric space for $S = (0,1]$ and $d(x,y) = |1/x - 1/y|$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $S$ be a half-open interval $(0,1]$. If we define $d$ on $S$ by

$$d(x,y) := \left|{1\over x} - {1\over y}\right|\;,$$

then show that $d$ is a metric on $S$. Also, prove that $(S,d)$ is a complete metric space.

I think that this problem would begin by showing the $3$ properties of a metric space. And then show that it is Cauchy?

Comment: No, once you’ve shown that $d$ is a metric, you need to show that every Cauchy sequence in $\langle S,d\rangle$ converges. Being Cauchy is a property of sequences, not of metrics or spaces. You can try to do that directly, but it might be easier to find an isometry between this space and the space $[1,\to)$ with the usual metric.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I know, I just meant to give an idea of what the space looked like. Take the wheel. =)

Comment: @Kathyrn : I would go with Brian's hint.  I think he means the space $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: @Pedro: I’ll admit that I started to make a somewhat similar suggestion, but then I decided that it had too much potential to confuse.

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, $[1,\to)$ is synonymous with $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott how to find the isometry ?

Comment: @Sade: I’d prefer not to say until Kathryn’s had a chance to think about it, but the function that you need for the isometry can be found somewhere in the definition of the metric $d$.

Comment: $f:(0,1]\to [1,\rightarrow),x\mapsto {1\over x}$ will do the job. Thank you.

Comment: @Kathryn: I’ll be happy to offer more help if you can be a bit more specific. Can you show that $d$ has any of the defining properties of a metric?

Comment: well, i know how to show the properties of a metric, as far as d(x,y)=0 iff x=y and d(x,y)=d(y,x) for every x,y in X and the third being the triangle inequality. I do not understand what the definition of isometric is asking me to prove, therefore the concept of a completion of a metric space is unclear as well

Comment: according to my text, an isometry is when a function f:(X,d) onto (Y,p) between 2 metrics and that if p(f(x),f(y))= d(x,y) holds for all x,y in X. This definition is confusing to me.

Comment: Okay; give me a few minutes, and I’ll write up an answer to get you at least started in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Just as two topological spaces are identical in terms of topological structure precisely when there is a homeomorphism between them, two metric spaces are identical in terms of metric structure precisely when there is an isometry between them. In both cases you could say that they’re the same space under a different name. My suggestion in the comments was that $S$ with the metric $d$ is structurally identical to the ray $[0,\to)$ with the usual metric. The idea is that a point $x\in S$ corresponds to $\frac1x\in[1,\to)$. This map $x\mapsto\frac1x$ really is an isometry: if $x,y\in S$, the $d$-distance between $x$ and $y$ is exactly the same as the ordinary distance between $\frac1x$ and $\frac1y$ in $[1,\to)$. And the space $[1,\to)$ with the usual metric is complete, so we can use this correspondence to show that $\langle S,d\rangle$ is complete as well.

Suppose that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\langle S,d\rangle$. This means that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $d(x_k,x_n)<\epsilon$ whenever $k,n\ge m$, i.e., that

$$\left|\frac1{x_k}-\frac1{x_n}\right|<\epsilon\qquad\text{whenever}\qquad k,n\ge m_\epsilon\;.$$

We want to show that the sequence converges to some $x\in S$. Look at the corresponding sequence $$\left\langle\frac1x_n:n\in\Bbb N\right\rangle\tag{1}$$ in $[1,\to)$. For convenience of notation let $y_n=\frac1{x_n}$, so that $(1)$ is just $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$. Is this a Cauchy sequence in $[1,\to)$ with the usual metric? Absolutely: if $k,n\ge m_\epsilon$ (that’s the same $m_\epsilon$ as before), then

$$|y_k-y_n|=\left|\frac1{x_k}-\frac1{x_n}\right|=d(x_k,x_n)<\epsilon\;.$$

And $[1,\to)$ is complete, so $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to some limit $y$.

At this point I’ve done most of it; can you use $y$ to find the limit of the original sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $S$ and show that what you find really is the limit?

Comment: oh, ok, i think i now get what it means when they say that two metrics have the same isometry, that makes perfect sense now. give me a minute to wrap my mind around the rest.

Comment: @Kathryn: It can’t: $0$ isn’t in $S$. You know that $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to y$, so for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $|y_n-y|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge m_\epsilon$. That means that $$\left|\frac1{x_n}-y\right|<\epsilon$$ whenever $n\ge m_\epsilon$. Can you use this to find an $x\in S$ such that $$d(x_n,x)=\left|\frac1{x_n}-\frac1x\right|<\epsilon$$ whenever $n\ge m_\epsilon$?